# How to ensure that the for loop does not change to next item on list untill if statement is satisfied

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, geometry

I want to have n number of cuboids with uniform distribution. I want to use each volume in this distribution to get height , width and depth within a range. I have written the code below.

```
import random 
import numpy as np

def cuboidimensions(minwidth,maxwidth , mindepth,maxdepth , minheight,maxheight, numberofcuboids ):
    cuboids = []
    minvolume = minwidth*mindepth*minheight
    maxvolume = maxwidth*maxdepth*maxheight
    cuboidvolume = list(np.random.uniform(minvolume,maxvolume,numberofcuboids))
    print(cuboidvolume)
    volumes = []
    while len(cuboids)<numberofcuboids:
        for i in cuboidvolume:
            width = random.uniform(minwidth,maxwidth)
            #print(roomwidth)
            bywidth = i/width
            height = random.uniform(minheight,maxheight)
            depth = bywidth/height
            if mindepth < depth < maxdepth :
                cuboid = [width , depth , height]
                cuboids.append(cuboid)
                volume = width * depth * height
                volumes.append(volume)
            else:
                #print('break')
                continue
                
       
    return  volumes ,cuboids                  
       
x = cuboidimensions(3,20,3,20,3,7,5) 

print(x)
```

The output example:

[442.28038126151915, 408.03629466149783, 1414.446813849802, 69.72740444974464, 1834.7672962439801]
([442.2803812615191, 408.03629466149783, 442.28038126151915, 408.0362946614979, 1414.446813849802], [[11.15009197449912, 5.681017397379145, 6.982213208200401], [13.53187840857758, 5.032921637235733, 5.991292736780531], [4.983376476038543, 15.4611798565468, 5.740257111137015], [8.655025551400598, 6.98071480906089, 6.753525517407468], [13.612476509177514, 15.56534197057105, 6.6756077754968945]])

What I want to change is that in the for loop, the same i value from the cuboidvolume should be used till the if condition is met. Like in output, the loop renews and gets 442 again. I do not want that.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get the required output

Comment: Even after reading again your question, I am not sure of what is the actual and expected output. You should make it more clear. Ideally, you should use `random.seed` to have reproducible values.

Comment: I generate list of uniformly distributed volumes. I then iterate through each volume, get random height and width within range. Next, I check if the depth I get is within range. If not, for the same volume I need to generate random width and height till my condition for range is met

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an internal loop until you can find an acceptable depth:

```
while len(cuboids)<numberofcuboids:
    for i in cuboidvolume:
        while True:                   # loop until an acceptable triple
            width = random.uniform(minwidth,maxwidth)
            #print(roomwidth)
            bywidth = i/width
            height = random.uniform(minheight,maxheight)
            depth = bywidth/height
            if mindepth < depth < maxdepth :       # ok we have found one
                cuboid = [width , depth , height]
                cuboids.append(cuboid)
                volume = width * depth * height
                volumes.append(volume)
                break                              # next cuboid
            # else:                          # uncomment for debug traces
            #     print('failed at', i)
```

With `np.random.seed(0)` (to get reproducible pseudo-random values) and the debugging traces uncommented it gives:

```
[1548.8598463904716, 2010.220112950719, 1698.4628418466684, 1537.961066450395, 1201.7947585667828]
failed at 1548.8598463904716
failed at 1548.8598463904716
failed at 1548.8598463904716
failed at 2010.220112950719
failed at 2010.220112950719
failed at 2010.220112950719
failed at 2010.220112950719
failed at 1698.4628418466684
failed at 1698.4628418466684
failed at 1537.961066450395
failed at 1201.7947585667828
([1548.8598463904716, 2010.220112950719, 1698.4628418466684, 1537.9610664503953, 1201.7947585667825],
 [[15.927467695800846, 16.58320187640551, 5.864041030688154],
  [19.17184015103345, 15.220726834681606, 6.888813429199256],
  [16.889820992705204, 16.61875454444647, 6.051074917131327],
  [18.980276722773763, 15.396238992759852, 5.262936833061211],
  [13.973450447268686, 13.116215446815685, 6.55719508432798]])
```

which proves that it had to retry before finding the acceptable values